# Symfony2: temporarily disable softdelete

Tags: php, symfony

I want to temporarily disable softdelete, so I can find deleted entities by ID and then really delete them in my unit tests (so to make sure I do not clog the database).

What I tried:

```
$this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeletable');
$item = $repository->findOneById($id); //fetch the item which was soft-deleted
$this->em->remove($item);
$this->em->flush();
```

But that throws an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException : Filter 'softdeletable' is not enabled.
```

I also tried disable('soft-deletable') and disable('soft-deleteable') etc - nothing worked. But when I look at $this->em->getFilters(), the filter is THERE:

```
["enabledFilters"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["softdeletable"]=>
      string(48) "Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter"
  }
```

Trying the code without the disable of course doesn't work either:

```
Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException : EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.
```

What am I doing wrong? I know I can really delete something with setting deletedAt to new DateTime but how do I delete an item without fetching it first?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using this in a loop or something? If so, the filter may already be disabled. You could do a check for whether it is enabled before disabling using `if ($this->em->getFilters()->isEnabled('softdeleteable'))...`

Comment: @Chi could you try `$filters = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->getFilters(); $filters->disable('softdeleteable');` and tell me if you have an error?

Comment: could you please provide an answer here which can get the accepted one?

Comment: @lolmx post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Originally a comment....***

Are you using this in a loop or something?
If so, the filter may already be disabled.

You could do a check for whether it is enabled before disabling using if like...

```
$this->em->getFilters()->isEnabled('softdeleteable'))...
```